# Is the -ie suffix commonly associated with femininity?

Tags: feminine

Is it valid to assume that the -ie suffix is commonly associated with femininity? Say, we take a word like *owl* and add the suffix, so we get *owlie*. Would a person whose native language is English be more likely to assume that *owlie* is a feminine sounding word? By extension, same for words like *sharkie*, *stormie*, etc.

If we take female names like *Carrie, Abbie, Kylie* and so on into consideration, my theory might not be entirely baseless.

Comment: Better not let Arnie see this.

Comment: Or Eddie.  Or owls.

Comment: As others have pointed out, it's the same suffix as in Arnie, Eddie, Billy, matey, smiley, bikie, sweetie. Like most everything in English, of gender it knows not.

Comment: ...or Bonnie Prince Charlie.

Comment: I would say adding an “ee” sound is recognized as a diminutive, and there is a cultural/gender bias allowing diminutives for women and children when we would not do the same for men.

Comment: @StephenS also with endearment.

Comment: The brief answer to your question is "no".

Comment: *Tradies* are generally not considered feminine, though more women are getting into the industry now than in the past.

Comment: In some Indian languages, certain nouns ending in 'ie...ee' sound is feminine gender. The sub-head 'key points' in this link https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/gender, talks about something similar.